# Recommended warning flags at O2 optimization level in gcc-4.8.1

Tags: c++, c, gcc, gcc-warning

I have recently moved from gcc-4.2.4 to gcc-4.8.1. What are the recommended gcc warning options at O2 optimization level in gcc-4.8.1?

I have been using following warning flags in gcc-4.2.4:
-Wall -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wsign-compare -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wnon-template-friend -Woverloaded-virtual -Wsign-promo

Comment: I'd recommend all of them (at least `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`), and only disable any that you really can't find a sensible way to fix. This is somewhat subjective, though.

Comment: I agree with Mike, it might be subjective but there is a clear answer: warnings are there to help the developer, let the compiler help you as much as possible. Fix the warnings :)

Comment: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` Don't forget `-Werror` otherwise your build script will proceed to run your (probably incorrect) program

Comment: By the way, the question asks about warning settings in regards to a specific optimization level. I don't really see how the two are related. Warnings are to catch mistakes during development, optimization flags are to ensure your program runs optimally (ideally after you've already got it as correct as you can)

Comment: @Brandin: some warning appears only with optimization enabled (as strict-aliasing...)

Comment: `-Werror` might be appropriate for your own code, but using it for 3rd party builds and autotools / configure scripts will often fail. Macros like `AC_LANG_SOURCE` are often the culprit.

Comment: I'm a fan of `-Weffc++` for C++ code, too, although some folks don't like that one.

Comment: `-Werror` is not a good idea for code other people will build: new/old compiler versions will always spew different warnings, making compilation fail, while there might not be anything strictly wrong. Use it as a development tool if you must, but don't force it on people by default.

Comment: @BrettHale @rubenvb Well noted, often I've had to track down usage of `-Werror` in a script to get a source package to build properly.

Answer (score 3):

The convention I promote is:

```
-Wall -Wextra -pedantic
```

Visit the GCC documentation for details on which specific flags this turns on.

Comment: that's quite a minimalistic approach, many of the flags he mentioned won't be enabled.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: It's not "minimalistic" at all. He asked "What are the recommended gcc warning options at O2 optimization level in gcc-4.8.1?", not "What are the GCC warning options that I shall list now?" If he wants to add more, he's certainly welcome to, but I recommend not doing so unless you know you need to for some specific reason.

Comment: any serious (open source) projects I saw uses at least a dozen more flags, so if that's your recommendation, then yes, I find it quite minimalistic...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Read my comment again. You start with that set (which is more than enough for any commercial projects I've worked on over my career -- is that "serious" enough for you?) then add more as and when you need them. The fact that you're talking about open source is rather telling, as the poor code quality often seen therein doubtless led to the requirement to open up more specific warning flags.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Karoly. There are some additional optimizations at O2 level in gcc-4.8.1 in addition to O2 optimizations in gcc-4.2.4. My question is: Are there any mandatory warning flags in addition to the above mentioned flags which I must enable when using O2 optimization and clean up those warnings in my code.

Comment: @RYUZAKI: What does optimisation level have to do with warnings? Your question is too general: you are just asserting that there are "some warnings" that you want "cleaned up" but, without telling us what they are, we can't help you. And I don't really see why you need that help: if there's a warning you don't want set, unset it. It's not rocket science.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I read your comments again. I don't see how it contradicts what I wrote...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit At higher level of optimization, GCC can produce additional warnings that do not appear when compiling at a lower level of optimization.
The code base is quite large. In fact it has grew to millions lines of code over the course of multiple years. So, even with addition of several warnings flags, the warnings in whole code grow out of control. Thus, adding unimportant warning flags and cleaning up all the warnings will become a humungous task.

Comment: I have seen some issues (signed integer overflow optimization in which gcc assumes that wraparound cannot take place will always return true for the statement a+1 > a ) with gcc-4.8.1 optimizations. That is why I also don't want to unset/supress any such warning which may result in any issue later.

Comment: @RYUZAKI: I've never heard of that. It sounds like the code is absolutely awful, though. Perhaps put some more effort into fixing _that_!

Comment: If the compiler give warning on specific optimization level, it probably mean someone has abused undefined behavior, which will bite you later with huge amount of debugging time. Even project with million of code it should be taken seriously, and it is worth to do,  to keep warning to be few, if not zero.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on which target you want to build.
For ubuntu I'd do:

```
CWARN   =-Wall -Wextra -Wattributes -Wbuiltin-macro-redefined -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wdeclaration-after-statement    \
         -Wdiv-by-zero -Wdouble-promotion -Wenum-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wimplicit-int -Winit-self -Wint-to-pointer-cast  \
         -Wjump-misses-init -Wlogical-op -Wmissing-braces -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wmissing-parameter-type          \
         -Woverflow -Wpointer-arith -Wpointer-sign -Wpointer-to-int-cast -Wredundant-decls -Wreturn-type -Wshadow        \
         -Wsign-compare -Wtype-limits -Wuninitialized -Wwrite-strings \
         -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-multichar -Wno-strict-aliasing
CXXWARN =-Wall -Wextra -Wattributes -Wbuiltin-macro-redefined -Wc++0x-compat -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wdiv-by-zero     \
         -Wdouble-promotion -Wenum-compare -Wfloat-equal -Winit-self -Wint-to-pointer-cast -Wlogical-op -Wmissing-braces \
         -Wmissing-field-initializers -Woverflow -Wpointer-arith -Wredundant-decls -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare \
         -Wsign-promo -Wtype-limits -Wuninitialized -Wwrite-strings \
         -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-multichar -Wno-strict-aliasing
```

For freestanding kernel development, I do:

```
CWARN    =-Wall -Wextra -Wattributes -Wbuiltin-macro-redefined -Wcast-align -Wconversion         \\
          -Wdiv-by-zero -Wdouble-promotion -Wenum-compare -Wfloat-equal -Winit-self              \\
          -Wint-to-pointer-cast -Wlogical-op -Wmissing-braces -Wmissing-field-initializers       \\
          -Woverflow -Wpointer-arith -Wredundant-decls -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare     \\
          -Wtype-limits -Wuninitialized -Wwrite-strings                                          \\
          -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-multichar -Wno-unused-but-set-variable \\
          -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-int -Wjump-misses-init -Wpointer-sign         \\
          -Wpointer-to-int-cast -Wmissing-parameter-type
CXXWARN  =-Wall -Wextra -Wattributes -Wbuiltin-macro-redefined -Wcast-align -Wconversion         \\
          -Wdiv-by-zero -Wdouble-promotion -Wenum-compare -Wfloat-equal -Winit-self              \\
          -Wint-to-pointer-cast -Wlogical-op -Wmissing-braces -Wmissing-field-initializers       \\
          -Woverflow -Wpointer-arith -Wredundant-decls -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare     \\
          -Wtype-limits -Wuninitialized -Wwrite-strings                                          \\
          -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-multichar -Wno-unused-but-set-variable \\
          -Wc++0x-compat  -Wsign-promo
```

Some of the warnings are ON with -Wextra or friends, but I just want to explicitly turn them ON, and it won't hurt if the command line isn't too long.

For android and iOS you may also want to turn off some warnings to reduce noise from the standard libraries.

In case you may wonder that's overkill with lots of flags, but it make the compiler to be honest to any bad programming practice, it may not from you but from your teammate.

Comment: I believe the list needs an update e.g. `-Wbuiltin-macro-redefined` and `-Wattributes` are now enabled by default.